# Dom parser is not working- output shown is all null

Tags: java, xml, parsing, dom

I want to parse this xml file called "Weather.xml" is shown below:

```
<?xml version ="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
   <weather> 
       <forecast_information>
                                    <city data="Pittsford, NY" />
                                    <postal_code data="14534" /> 
                                    <forecast_date data="2015-03-12" /> 
                                    <unit_system data="US" />
                                  <condition data = "Mostly Cloudy" /> 
                                   <temp_f data ="42" /> 
                                   <wind_condition data="Wind: NW at 7 mph" /> 
                                    <day_of_week data="Sat" /> 
                                    <low data="32"/> 
                                   <high data = "45" />
                                   <condition data="Rain and Snow" />
          </forecast_information>
         <forecast_information> 
                                    <city data= "Rochester, NY" /> 
                                    <postal_code data="14623" /> 
                                   <forecast_date data= "2015-03-12" /> 
                                   <unit_system data="US" /> 
                                    <condition data="Partly Cloudy" /> 
                                    <temp_f data="40" />
                                    <wind_condition data="Wind: St at 3.5 mph"       />
                                     <day_of_week data="Mon" /> 
                                     <low data="30" /> 
                                     <high data="40" />
                                     <condition data="Bright and Sunny" />
            </forecast_information> 
   </weather>
```

I have coded the DOM parser for it in the following way:

```
public class DomParserDemo {
 public static void main(String[] args){

  try { 
     File inputFile = new File("Weather.xml");
     DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory 
        = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
     DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
     Document doc = dBuilder.parse(inputFile);
     doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
     System.out.println("Root element :" 
        + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
     NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("forecast_information");
     System.out.println("----------------------------");
     for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {
        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        System.out.println("\nCurrent Element :" 
           + nNode.getNodeName());
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
           Element eElement = (Element) nNode;
           System.out.println("City : " + eElement.getAttribute("city"));

           System.out.println("Postal_Code : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("postal_code").item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Forecast date : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("forecast_date").item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Unit System : " + eElement .getElementsByTagName("unit_system") .item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Condition : " + eElement .getElementsByTagName("condition") .item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Wind Condition : " + eElement .getElementsByTagName("wind_condition") .item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Day of week : " + eElement .getElementsByTagName("day_of_week") .item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println("Low : " + eElement .getElementsByTagName("low") .item(0).getTextContent());
           System.out.println("High: " + eElement .getElementsByTagName("high") .item(0).getTextContent());




        }
     }
  } catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
 }
```

But the output shown is as follows, the information is not being extracted from the .xml file I provided:

```
   Root element :weather
   ----------------------------

   Current Element :forecast_information
   City : 
   Postal_Code : 
   Forecast date : 
   Unit System : 
   Condition : 
   Wind Condition : 
   Day of week : 
   Low : 
   High: 

   Current Element :forecast_information
   City : 
   Postal_Code : 
   Forecast date : 
   Unit System : 
   Condition : 
   Wind Condition : 
   Day of week : 
   Low : 
   High:
```

Comment: You can also do the following ... eElement.getElementsByTagName("postal_code").item(0).getAttributes().getNamedItem("data")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First mistake:**

```
System.out.println("City : " + eElement.getAttribute("city"));
```

You are asking for an attribute of your element named `city`, but the `forecast_information` element doesn't have any attributes. `city` is a *child element* of `forecast_information`, thus you should extract it either by traversing children or by using `getElementsByTagName()` as you do with the rest of the items.

**Second mistake:**

For all the other elements, you are doing `getElementsByTagName`, which works fine for retrieving the element itself. However, the `data` item which you want to retrieve is not their content - it's an attribute.

Using `getTextContent()` would be correct if the items looked like this:

```xml
<forecast_date>2015-03-12</forecast_date> 
<unit_system>US</unit_system>
```

But this is not how your XML is formatted. In your XML, you need to retrieve the attribute `data`. So you should replace the calls like:

```
System.out.println("Postal_Code : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("postal_code").item(0).getTextContent());
```

To:

```
System.out.println("Postal_Code : " + eElement.getElementsByTagName("postal_code").item(0).getAttribute("data"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In all your tags, there is no content. The `data` is an attribute, hence you need to get the value of the attribute using `eElement.getAttribute("data");`